C++ idiom for a map of template argument to value of template-instance type?
I have an enum class, say
enum class color { Red, Green, Blue, /* etc. */};

and I have class template,
template <color Color> class foo;

Now, I want to declare a data type which holds, for some (or all) possible values of color, a value of type foo<color>; and I want to be able to insert and remove such mappings at run-time.
So, I want something like an unordered_map from color to foo, except that for a given color, the mapping is not actually to any foo, only to foo<color>.
The closest thing I can think of using, that's also terse, is a
using MyMap = std::tuple<color::Blue, color::Red, color::Green>

(or perhaps std::optional's of each of these foo's), so that given the color, I can use std::get<foo<MyColor>>(my_map)); and I can also write a getter which takes an actual color at compile-time:
template <color Color>
foo<Color> get(const MyMap& map)
{ return std::get<foo<Color>>(map); }

but all that is a bit unwieldy. Can I do better?
Notes:

In case there is nothing mapped from some color value - I don't mind the exact behavior: It could be an exception, returning a nullopt, or even failing to compile if your structure can only be filled at compile-time.
You may use newer C++ language versions if you like (even C++26 if that helps you), but the less outlandish we need to be, the better.


What should the getter function return in case there is no mapping for the supplied color in the map?

Ok, then would a simple std::array<bool, number_of_colors> do?  example

"A mapping from color to foo<color>" sounds like "dependent typing", which C++ does not have natively. Expressions in C++ have a statically decided type. However, if you'd be OK with a function template and the lookup key is statically known, then I wouldn't find get<Red>() all that bad. That's basically just like the variant interface. (Indeed, a single function, dynamic get could return a variant.)

Encapsulate a std::variant and define accessors with compile time color NTTP: template<color> auto* get(color_var const&); and auto& put(color_var&, auto&&); plus color to_color(color_var const&);.

@Red.Wave: That could be an answer...

I would start with adapting std::variant:
#include <variant>

class color_var{
public:
    enum color: std::uint_8{/*list the colors*/};

    color_var(auto&& x) //the actual setter
    :   m_var{std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)}{};

    template<color what>
    friend auto* get(color_var const &that){
        std::size_t constexpr n{std::to_underlying(what)};
        return (to_color(that) == what)
             ? std::addressof(get<n>(that.m_var))
             : nullptr;
    };//! get<what>

    friend color to_color(color_var const &that){
       return color{static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<color>>(index(that.m_var))};
    };//! to_color

    friend auto& to_variant(color_var const &that)
    { return that.m_var; };

private:
     std::variant</*list of types*/> m_var;
};//! class color_var

The provided constructor plays the put/assignment role. But this class is not default constructible, because the preferred color is not known to me. You can set any value and the color will be automatically adjusted:
color_var cv = type1_in_list{/*init*/};
assert((to_color(cv)==color_var::color1_in_list));
type2_in_list value2{/*init*/};
cv = value2;
assert((to_color(cv)==color_var::color2_in_list));

When the color is already known a none-owning pointer to value can be retrieved for immediate use:
assert((to_color(cv)==my_color));
assert((get<my_color>(cv)));
use(*get<my_color>(cv));

But the best usage is to visit the variant:
auto result = std::visit([](auto& value{
    if constexpr(std::same_as<type1, remove_cvref_t<decltype(value)>)
       return true;
    return false;
}, to_variant(cv));

std::visit is the fastest, safest and most readable way to access a variant. You don't actually need an if  statement inside the lambda, if your type list all use some common duck type features.
I prefer friend functions over none-virtual public members, because of syntax clarity. But you can make them members instead.
There's more meta programming involved, if the return types of functions need be explicitly specified instead of deduced.
Moreover, I believe free functions that are part of the static interface of a type should use ADL; So I intentionally dropped the std:: prefix on std::variant interface functions.
The std::variant class template has a convenient interface. For most use cases I would directly use it, but in case the exessive access methods seem harmful, encapsulation can leash its power(as in current discussion). The to_variant function I provided is a conservative measure for unforseen usage as patchband. If it is eventually used, the code may need a revision.
Important Update:
I discovered a problem with copy/move constructors in my primary answer.
This is a fast patch:
template<typename in>
requires std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<in>, color_var>
color_var::color_var(in&& init)
:   m_var{std::forward<in>(init).m_var}{};

The other constructor can be patched like this:(inverse requrements to the above)
template<typename in>
requires std::constructible_from<color_var, in> and
not std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<in>, color_var>
color_var::color_var(in&& init)
:   m_var{std::forward<in>(init)}{};

This is a common problem in single argument template constructors.

It must be there now. You need not copy/paste everything. All the std functions and class are provided for further research.

std::variant is a good approach here.  We can do it with algebra on types.
First, a compile time constamt stored in a runtime variable:
template<auto x>
using k_t=std::integral_constant<decltype(x), x>;
template<auto x>
constexpr k_t<x> k_v={};

these are fun toys: they are values whose "real" value is stored in their type.
We can make variants of these:
template<auto...xs>
using venum_t=std::variant<k_t<xs>...>;

and we can build them from ranges:
template<auto start, unsigned count>
using venum_range_t=/* venum_t<start through start+count-1> */;
with that last one being pseudocode, because the implementation is verbose.
Once you have your variant:
using my_venum=venum_t<color::ted, color::blue, color::green>;

aka
using my_venum=venum_range_t<color::red, 3>;

The next piece is code that turns a runtime value unto a venum.  For the range case it is:
template<auto start, unsigned count, std::size_t...Is >
venum_range_t<start, count> make_venum( decltype(start) const& v, std::index_sequence<Is...> ){
  using R=venum_range_t<start, count>;
  using F=R(*)();
  F retval[count]={
    []()->R{ return k_v<decltype(start)(start+Is)>; }...
  };
  return retval[v-start]();
}
template<auto start, unsigned count>
auto make_venum( decltype(start) v ){
  return make_venum<start, count>(v, std::make_index_sequence<count>{} );
}

Next step, we can make one for your template return types:
using my_result_t=std::variant<foo<color::red>, foo<color::blue>, foo<color::green>>;

this can be generated from the my_venum type if needed.
We now attach them:
my_result_t make_foo(color c){
  auto v=make_venum<color::red, 3>(c);
  return std::visit( [](auto c)->my_result_t {
    return foo<c>{}; // ?!?!?!
  }, v);
}

The magic of the rest of the code lets us write business logic at // ?!?!?! where we take our runtime c value and use it in a compile time context.
Your data structure should hold a map from color to my_result_t, a variant of foo types.
Once you have it you have to std visit to get the real type out.
